# The resource could not be found in jclouds

Tags: openstack-swift, jclouds

I got this when I am trying

```
04:59:49.489 [main] DEBUG jclouds.wire` - << 

<html><h1>Not Found</h1><p>The resource could not be found.</p></html>
null

04:59:49.520 [main] DEBUG o.j.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod - >> invoking container:list
04:59:49.521 [main] DEBUG o.j.h.i.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService - Sending request -1849476372: GET http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8080/v1/AUTH_2c5c2fbbfe22422496d5ebf6861199f2/?format=json HTTP/1.1
04:59:49.521 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> GET http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8080/v1/AUTH_2c5c2fbbfe22422496d5ebf6861199f2/?format=json HTTP/1.1
04:59:49.522 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> Accept: application/json
04:59:49.522 [main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Auth-Token:
```

At line

`swiftApi.getObjectApiForRegionAndContainer("RegionOne", CONTAINER_NAME).get(OBJECT_NAME)`;

how to resolve this

Please share any links or sample application related to content retrieval from openstack by jclouds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Swift example in the jclouds OpenStack Guide](http://jclouds.apache.org/guides/openstack/#swift). I just tried it on a DevStack instance and it's working.

If you can get that to work, you should be able to get your own code to work too.